# COBOL: remove certain characters from string

Tags: string, cobol

I would like to remove certain characters from a string in COBOL.
For example, '****This is*a test** string.' will become 'This isa test string.', '"Second one"' will become 'Second one'.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Still thinking, inspect may not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code snippet.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD. 
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
01 WS-STR PIC X(20) VALUE '****This is*a test**'. 
01 WS-CNT PIC 99 VALUE 0.
01 WS-I PIC 99 VALUE 0.
01 WS-J PIC 99 VALUE 1.
01 WS-CHAR.
   05 WS-LETTER OCCURS 1 TO 20 TIMES DEPENDING ON WS-CNT PIC X.
PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
PERFORM VARYING WS-I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL WS-I > FUNCTION LENGTH(WS-STR)
IF WS-STR(WS-I:1) = '*' THEN
CONTINUE
ELSE
MOVE WS-STR(WS-I:1) TO WS-LETTER(WS-J)
ADD 1 TO WS-J
ADD 1 TO WS-CNT
END-IF
END-PERFORM
DISPLAY WS-CHAR
STOP RUN.
```

Output:

```
This isa test
```

Note: I used Tutorial Point's COBOL Coding ground to run the above snippet. COBOL Code doesn't need to be indented there.

Answer (score 1):

While `INSPECT ... REPLACING` cannot change the position of characters within a data item, `INSPECT ... CONVERTING` may be used to prepare the data item for subsequent operations.

In the following, the procedure `strip-string` first converts all characters, to be replaced, to a single common character, in this case, `LOW-VALUES`. This fragments the string so that the common character maybe be used to easily delimit the fragments. The `PERFORM` loops over the fragmented string. The `UNSTRING` statement moves one fragment to the output and provides a `COUNT` of the number of characters moved. The `ADD` augments the output starting position so that the fragments are positioned in sequence.

---

Code:

```
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 binary.
    2 p pic 9(4).
    2 o pic 9(4).
    2 o-count pic 9(4).
   1 i-string pic x(40).
     88 test-1 value '****This is*a test** string.'.
     88 test-2 value '"Second one"'.
   1 o-string pic x(40).
   1 r-chars pic x(2) value '*"'. *> characters to be removed
   procedure division.
   begin.
       set test-1 to true
       perform test-prep
       set test-2 to true
       perform test-prep
       stop run
       .

   test-prep.
       display i-string
       perform strip-string
       display o-string
       display space
       .

   strip-string.
       inspect i-string converting r-chars to low-values
       move 1 to p o
       perform until p > function length (i-string)
           unstring i-string
               delimited all low-values
               into o-string (o:)
               count in o-count
               with pointer p
           add o-count to o
       end-perform
       .
```

Output:

```
****This is*a test** string.
This isa test string.

"Second one"
Second one
```